# Does macOS Mojave (10.14) support 32 - bit Apps?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32-bit, mojave

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208436), 32-Bit apps will lose support soon.  When opening 32 - bit applications on macOS High Sierra I was prompted with a message stating that in future versions of macOS the app would not be supported. This was similar to messages on iOS 10, on opening soon-to-be unsupported applications. These applications lost support in iOS 11.  So, does macOS Mojave, a future version of macOS, support 32-bit applications and allow you to open and use them?

Comment: Apple could shut off 32 bit support on High Sierra - there’s no reason other than social why they don’t push a small change there as well. Just so we’re clear on technical reasons as opposed to support being a purely human decision at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's confirmed on the State of the Union that the final version of macOS 10.14 Mojave support 32-bit and it will be the last macOS that support it.

From https://www.macstories.net/news/macos-mojave-a-roundup-of-all-the-little-things/

> The Final Version to Support 32-Bit Apps. During the State of the Union presentation, Apple confirmed that Mojave will be the last version of macOS to support 32-bit apps. When a user tries to open a 32-bit app, Mojave currently displays a one-time warning that the app will not work in future versions of macOS.

Or watch the Platforms State of the Union video at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/102/

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Josh, Watch the Platforms State of the Union - WWDC 2018 video. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/102/

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**

As of macOS Mojave (10.14) beta 9, macOS Mojave **DOES** support 32 - bit applications. When opening these applications, you will see a dialog box with a similar message from High Sierra (see below) telling you that "This app will not work with future versions of macOS" but after clicking "Ok" the application will open.

For example, I attempted to open an old version of Firefox (3.16.14 from 2010) that is 32 - bit and got this message

[image]

After pressing "Ok" it opened

[image]

[image]

Sorry about Spanish, only version I could find.

Comment: Will edit this answer as beta's continue to the final release. And will probably mark as answered once the final is released.